# Would $\nu/k$ be a meaningful timescale in turbulence?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, physical-constants, viscosity, turbulence

If we consider kinematic viscosity $\nu \, [\text{m}^2/\text{s}]$ and turbulence kinetic energy $k \, [\text{m}^2/\text{s}^2]$, we can form a timescale
$$
  \tau = \frac{\nu}{k}.
$$

Is it a meaningful timescale? For example at low Reynolds number or close to a wall. I understand that it behaves weird, decreasing with an increase of turbulence intensity and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible meaning for it may be the following:

The bulk of turbulent kinetic energy (per unit mass) $k$ resides in the large scales of turbulent motion. The dissipation occurs at the smallest scales of motion, known as Kolmogorov scales, and it is here alone that $\nu$ becomes important. So you see $k$ and $\nu$ belong to opposite ends of the scales of turbulent motion.  Therefore for the time scale $\tau\equiv\nu/k$ to have physical meaning there must be some physical mechanism connecting the two scales. There is such a physical mechanism, the so-called *energy cascade* in turbulence.

The idea of energy cascade is that kinetic energy contained in large scales of turbulent motion must be ultimately dissipated away at small scales, and therefore by some mechanism (which we need go into here) kinetic energy flows (in some abstract sense of the word) from large scales to small where it is dissipated into heat by viscous mechanism.

In statistically steady turbulence, it is reasonable to assume that the rate at which energy flows from large to small scales is proportional to the kinetic energy contained in the large scales viz. $k$. This means that more vigorous the turbulence more quickly does it dissipate its kinetic energy, to maintain a statistically steady state. If $T$ be the time scale in which kinetic energy in large motion "flows" to small scales then the dissipation rate per unit mass $\epsilon$ must equal it to maintain statistically steady state. Therefore in an order of magnitude sense: $\epsilon\sim k/T$. In statistically steady turbulence $T$ is assumed (due to G.I. Taylor) to be of the same order the large eddy turnover time (see [here](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~mcmurtry/Turbulence/turblt.pdf)).

Now Kolomogorov time scale $\tau_K$ at which dissipation occurs is given by: $\tau_K\sim \sqrt{\nu/\epsilon}\sim\sqrt{T(\nu/k)}\sim\sqrt{T\tau}$. Therefore $\tau/T\sim(\tau_k/T)^2\sim 1/Re_L$, in which $Re_L$ is Reynolds number based on large eddy scales. Therefore increasing turbulence intensity achieved by increasing Reynolds number decreases $\tau$ relative to large eddy turnover time $T$.